# Why in Presto, it shows cardinality function is "Python function"?

Tags: presto

But this cardinality function doesn't exist in Python though..
[https://prestodb.io/docs/current/search.html?q=cardinality+function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tDWt.png)